# Erro ao tentar escrever acentos em arquivos com Python

Tags: python, unicode

Eu estava tentado fazer um programa em Python que pudesse fazer alterações em outro arquivo .py para poder alterar seu código automaticamente. Fui fazer o seguinte teste no Shell antes de escrever o programa em si:

```
>>> import os
>>> file = open(os.path.abspath('.') + 'outroarquivo.py', 'a+')
>>> file.write("Quero caféééééééé!")
```

O texto foi bastante aleatório, pois era só pra testar, mas essa última linha deu o seguinte retorno:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#37>", line 1, in <module>
    file.write("Quero caféééééééé!")
UnicodeEncodeError: 'cp932' codec can't encode character '\xe9' in position 9: illegal multibyte sequence
```

Isso ocorre sempre que tento por algum acento ou ç dentro do parâmetro de `.write()`.
Alguém pode me ajudar a resolver isso? Talvez haja alguma forma de mudar o codec?

Comment: Dê uma procurada no stackoverflow em português- essas questões de acentuação aparecem muitas vezes. E sobretudo, leia http://local.joelonsoftware.com/wiki/O_M%C3%ADnimo_Absoluto_Que_Todos_os_Programadores_de_Software_Precisam,_Absolutamente,_Positivamente_de_Saber_Sobre_Unicode_e_Conjuntos_de_Caracteres_(Sem_Desculpas!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fazendo mais alguns testes no Shell, ele acabou me dando uma ajudinha. Quando fui digitar o comando `open`, o programa mostrou os parâmetros dessa função:

```
>>> open(filse, mode='r', buffering=-1, encoding=None)
```

Já que o problema é com o codec `cp932` que não conseguia fazer o encode dos caracteres, acabou sendo bem simples resolver, foi só mudar o argumento `encoding`:

```
>>> file = open(os.path.abspath(".") + "\\outroarquivo.py", "w", -1, "utf-8")
>>> file.write("Quero caféééééééé!")
```

Foi só manter o `buffering` com seu valor padrão = -1, e mudar o `encoding` para o `utf-8`, que é o padrão utilizado no Brasil.
Na hora de ler o que foi escrito no arquivo, tive que fazer a mesma coisa (só substituindo `"w"` por `"r"` ou `"a"`), pois se não saia um negócio bizarro:

```
>>> file = open(os.path.abspath(".") + "\\outroarquivo.py", "r")
>>> ler = file.read()
>>> ler
'Quero cafﾃｩﾃｩﾃｩﾃｩﾃｩﾃｩﾃｩﾃｩ!'
```

Muito obrigado a todos que deixaram suas respostas, tenho certeza que serão úteis caso mais alguém tenha algum problema parecido!

Answer (score 1):

tente o seguinte:

```
str(file.write("Quero caféééééééé!")).encode(encoding='UTF-8',errors='strict')
```

Eu tive um problema parecido hoje e resolvi assim, espero ter ajudado.

Answer (score 0):

Tente adicionar a declaração de encoding no inicio do arquivo .py

```
#-*- coding:utf-8 -*-
```

Comment: Isso para o arquivo onde você irá executar o open.

Comment: Declarar o encoding não é "mágica",. Não resolve nada no caso.

Comment: Mas eu disse que era mágica?  Eu reproduzi o problema dele e resolveu.

Comment: Testei no meu pc e continuou dando erro. Talvez a gente utilize interpretadores diferentes ou sei lá, então pode ser que ainda funcione para outras pessoas, caso elas vejam algum erro parecido.
Andei dando uma olhada na net, e pelo que entendi essa primeira linha que você sugeriu serve mais pra indicar o encoding do próprio código do programa do que o encoding dos arquivos que ele abre e manipula.
De qualquer forma, muito obrigado aos dois pela preocupação em resolver o problema!

Comment: Você não "reproduziu o problema dele"  - se você dixar de colcocar o encoding, num arquivo de Python 2, você tem um "SntaxError" - o erro dele foi "UnicodeEncodeError". Se você não sabe oq eu está acontecendo, está tentando resolverpor tentativa e erro: portanto é "mágica".

Comment: jsbueno, tens razão, eu só consegui reproduzir um erro de Syntax, provavelmente o problema dele seja mais complexo, desculpem pelo engano. Vi que você deixou um artigo sobre encoding. Realmente esses problemas quando me deparo eu vou por tentativa e erro mesmo, mas vou dar uma lida pra entender melhor como resolver. Valeu e desculpe novamente !

Answer (score 0):

Se for rodar o programa em Windows, prefira cp1252 ao invés de UTF-8 no comentário funcional da codificação de caracter; funciona melhor.