# Como manipular formulários html no python

Tags: python, python-3.x, codificação-de-caracteres, xampp, cgi

Precisava de uma ajuda com os formulários em cgi no python.
Este código funciona normalmente quando não insiro acentos:

```
# !/Programas/Python36-32/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import cgi
print("Content-Type: text/html; UTF-8\n")
form = cgi.FieldStorage()
web_page="""
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>    
    <title>O Meu primeiro programa</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post">
        Name:     <input type="text" name="name"><br>
        Password: <input type="text" name="password"><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
"""
print(web_page)
name=form["name"].value
password=form["password"].value
print("name: "+name)
print("<br>")
print("password: "+password)
with open("file.txt", "w") as f:
    f.write("name: "+name+"\n"+"password: "+password)
```

Mas simplesmente não escreve nada no ficheiro quando eu coloco acentos.
Alguém me pode ajudar a gravar os dados dos campos num ficheiro?

**Nota:** Eu uso o servidor XAMPP, versão 3.2.2 com o apache versão 2.4.29 e python versão 3.6.2

Comment: Já experimentou definir o _charset_ no HTML também? Tente inserir `<meta charset="utf-8">` no `<head>`

Comment: **OBSERVAÇÃO:** O módulo [Python cgi](https://docs.python.org/3/library/cgi.html) se tornou *obsoleto desde a versão 3.11, será removido na versão 3.13* (consulte [PEP 594](https://peps.python.org/pep-0594/#cgi) para detalhes e alternativas).

Answer (score 1):

Quando as variáveis `name` e `password` passam pelo `print`, elas são impressas corretamente? Se sim, o problema é provavelmente no `open` em sua encodificação.

Dê uma olhada [neste link](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/198121/erro-ao-tentar-escrever-acentos-em-arquivos-com-python) sobre encoding. Talvez resolva seu problema:

```
with open("file.txt", "w", encoding='utf-8') as f:
    f.write("name: "+name+"\n"+"password: "+password)
```

Comment: Olá, não funcionou, continua a não escrever nada no arquivo, nem mesmo "name: " e "password: " e não consigo imprimir com o `print` os valores, só se codificar para um encode e usar a função `repr` e, depois, não consigo descodificar para um formato legível.

Answer (score 1):

Conforme a [*issue 10219*](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/10219), esse comportamento está devido ao fato das versões do Python 3.6 e inferiores não adotarem a codificação **UTF-8** implicitamente, mas [**ANSI_X3.4-1968** (ou **ASCII**) para **`sys.stdout.encoding`** por padrão](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19574801/12195738).

Para contornar essa situação, basta acrescentar no arquivo `httpd.conf` (ou `apache2.conf` em algumas distribuições Linux) a variável de ambiente `PYTHONIOENCODING`, que será definida a nível do processo do servidor web e para os scripts CGI invocados.

Deverá então ser adicionado o seguinte ao arquivo de configuração do servidor Apache:

```plaintext
SetEnv PYTHONIOENCODING UTF-8
```

Alternativamente, também é possível definir um arquivo `.htaccess` no diretório que hospeda o CGI e adicionar a variável de ambiente dessa mesma forma.

---

No caso de servidores Linux, é possível também definir essa variável no arquivo de configuração `envvars` localizado no diretório `/etc/apache2` da seguinte forma:

```sh
export PYTHONIOENCODING='UTF-8'

## OU (desde que o sistema esteja configurado com suporte a caracteres UTF-8)
# . /etc/default/locale
```

Então, no arquivo de configuração referente aos diretórios que contém os scripts CGI, deve ser adicionada a seguinte diretiva:

```plaintext
PassEnv PYTHONIOENCODING

## ** OU (caso esteja utilizando '/etc/default/locale') **
# PassEnv LANG
```

---

Por fim basta reiniciar o servidor Apache e o CGI deverá funcionar conforme esperado para caracteres com acentuação.

**OBS.:** Esta solução é compatível das versões `2.x` até a `3.6` do Python; acima disso, essa configuração já é adotada por padrão — a partir da versão `3.7.0` —, de acordo com a [PEP 538](https://peps.python.org/pep-0538/).